# Watir not waiting for elements to load

Tags: ruby, selenium, automated-tests, cucumber, watir

In my test automation I am currently clicking on page elements in this manner:
sleep 2

```
  on(MyPage).generate_button_element.when_present.click
  sleep 5
  on(MyPage).button.when_present.click
```

In the above, I click on "generate_button" which would run some JS, create a button and then click ont he next button. In this case, it works. However, I would like to know if there is a way I can remove the sleep calls. I have tried the following:

```
  on(MyPage).generate_button_element.wait_until_present.click
  on(MyPage).button.wait_until_present.click
```

But it does not work. I get the following error:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: unknown error: Element
```

Is there any way I can have watir wait for such elements or are the sleeps my only option?

Debugging logger output:

```
"2017-10-04 14:15:41 INFO Selenium <- {"sessionId":"3db2d4a2c23ddd03e43622f3dfcbbab7","status":12,"value":{"message":"invalid element state: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated\n  (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488774 (7e15618d1bf16df8bf0ecf2914ed1964a387ba0b),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.6 x86_64)"}}
"
```

Comment: What version of Watir are you using? With the latest version of Watir, the hope is that you shouldn't need any explicit waits. Also what version of Page-Object are you using?

Comment: I am using page-object 2.2 and Watir 6.7.3. If I updated it to a latter version of watir my program was not working as I believe it broke page-object.

Comment: A number waiting related bugs/issues were fixed in the Watir 6.8.x releases. Page-Object 2.3 had some updates to address changes made in Watir 6.8. I'd suggest trying to upgrade both gems and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: 2.3? I am seeing 2.2.4 as the latest version.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I read the change log wrong. I meant [2.2.3](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/blob/master/ChangeLog).

Comment: I am now using latest versions of both Watir and Page-Object. Seems like waits have to be used here.

Comment: Do you still need the sleep and the waits or just the waits? It'd help if you could create a page that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I need sleep (duration). I have included a line from the debugger log which shows the part of failure. From the Slack channel, I was advised to open an issue for it on watirs github page.

Comment: Sure. One thing I would suggest you do is try using just the Watir code. It would help to know if the problem is Page-Object vs Watir.

Comment: If you could either include the HTML (before and after the first click) or a reference to the page, and then just pure watir code (sans the page object) we should be able to better assist you.

Comment: overall, watir has no way to know when JS code is running and it needs to wait for the page to be updated.  In general if you use a selector that is not present before the JS runs, and is present after, then watir should automagically wait for the element to be present before trying to act on it.. even then race conditions are possible depending on delays between when html is updated, and elements are ready to be interacted with.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't that it's trying to click the button when it's not there, but it's trying to click it before it's ready. Look at the button and see if you can't find an attribute that is only there when it's ready, like a class or on click event. Next use wait_until to wait until that attribute is in the ready state.

It should look something like this:

on(MyPage).generate_button_element.when_present.click

on(MyPage).wait_until { on(MyPage).button_element.attribute_value('class').eql? 'ready'}

on(MyPage).button